# Use AWK with delimiter to print specific columns

Tags: bash, unix, awk

My file looks as follows:

```
+------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+
| Message                                  | Status        | Adress         | Changes          | Test             | Calibration     |
|------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------|
| Hello World                              | Active        | up             |                1 |               up |            done |
| Hello Everyone Here                      | Passive       | up             |                2 |             down |            none |
| Hi there. My name is Eric. How are you?  | Down          | up             |                3 |         inactive |            done |
+------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+
+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+
| Message                    | Status        | Adress         | Changes          | Test             | Calibration     |
|----------------------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------|
| What's up?                 | Active        | up             |                1 |               up |            done |
| Hi. I'm Otilia             | Passive       | up             |                2 |             down |            none |
| Hi there. This is Marcus   | Up            | up             |                3 |         inactive |            done |
+----------------------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

I want to extract a specific column using AWK.
I can use CUT to do it; however when the length of each table varies depending on how many characters are present in each column, I'm not getting the desired output.

```
cat File.txt | cut -c -44
+------------------------------------------+
| Message                                  |
|------------------------------------------+
| Hello World                              |
| Hello Everyone Here                      |
| Hi there. My name is Eric. How are you?  |
+------------------------------------------+
+----------------------------+--------------
| Message                    | Status
|----------------------------+--------------
| What's up?                 | Active
| Hi. I'm Otilia             | Passive
| Hi there. This is Marcus   | Up
+----------------------------+--------------
```

or

```
cat File.txt | cut -c 44-60
+---------------+
| Status        |
+---------------+
| Active        |
| Passive       |
| Down          |
+---------------+
--+--------------
  | Adress
--+--------------
  | up
  | up
  | up
--+--------------
```

I tried using AWK but I don't know how to add 2 different delimiters which would take care of all the lines.

```
cat File.txt | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|";}{print $2,$3}'

 Message                                    Status
------------------------------------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------
 Hello World                                Active
 Hello Everyone Here                        Passive
 Hi there. My name is Eric. How are you?    Down


 Message                      Status
----------------------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------
 What's up?                   Active
 Hi. I'm Otilia               Passive
 Hi there. This is Marcus     Up
```

***The output I'm looking for:***

```
+------------------------------------------+
| Message                                  |
|------------------------------------------+
| Hello World                              |
| Hello Everyone Here                      |
| Hi there. My name is Eric. How are you?  |
+------------------------------------------+
+----------------------------+
| Message                    |
|----------------------------+
| What's up?                 | 
| Hi. I'm Otilia             | 
| Hi there. This is Marcus   | 
+----------------------------+
```

or

```
+------------------------------------------+---------------+
| Message                                  | Status        |
|------------------------------------------+---------------+
| Hello World                              | Active        |
| Hello Everyone Here                      | Passive       |
| Hi there. My name is Eric. How are you?  | Down          |
+------------------------------------------+---------------+
+----------------------------+---------------+
| Message                    | Status        | 
|----------------------------+---------------+
| What's up?                 | Active        | 
| Hi. I'm Otilia             | Passive       | 
| Hi there. This is Marcus   | Up            | 
+----------------------------+---------------+
```

or random other columns

```
+------------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+
| Message                                  | Adress         | Test             |
|------------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+
| Hello World                              | up             |               up |
| Hello Everyone Here                      | up             |             down |
| Hi there. My name is Eric. How are you?  | up             |         inactive |
+------------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+
+----------------------------+---------------+------------------+
| Message                    |Adress         | Test             |
|----------------------------+---------------+------------------+
| What's up?                 |up             |               up |
| Hi. I'm Otilia             |up             |             down |
| Hi there. This is Marcus   |up             |         inactive |
+----------------------------+---------------+------------------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One idea using `GNU awk`:

```
awk -v fldlist="2,3" '
BEGIN { fldcnt=split(fldlist,fields,",") }                      # split fldlist into array fields[]

      { split($0,arr,/[|+]/,seps)                               # split current line on dual delimiters "|" and "+"
        for (i=1;i<=fldcnt;i++)                                 # loop through our array of fields (fldlist)
            printf "%s%s", seps[fields[i]-1], arr[fields[i]]    # print leading separator/delimiter and field
        printf "%s\n", seps[fields[fldcnt]]                     # print trailing separator/delimiter and terminate line
      }
' File.txt
```

**NOTES:**

- requires `GNU awk` for the 4th argument to the `split()` function (`seps` == array of separators; see [gawk string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) for details)
- assumes our field delimiters (`|`, `+`) do not show up as part of the data
- the input variable `fldlist` is a comma-delimited list of columns that mimics what would be passed to `cut` (eg, when a line starts with a delimiter then field #1 is blank)

For `fldlist="2,3"` this generates:

```
+------------------------------------------+---------------+
| Message                                  | Status        |
|------------------------------------------+---------------+
| Hello World                              | Active        |
| Hello Everyone Here                      | Passive       |
| Hi there. My name is Eric. How are you?  | Down          |
+------------------------------------------+---------------+
+----------------------------+---------------+
| Message                    | Status        |
|----------------------------+---------------+
| What's up?                 | Active        |
| Hi. I'm Otilia             | Passive       |
| Hi there. This is Marcus   | Up            |
+----------------------------+---------------+
```

For `fldlist="2,4,6"` this generates:

```
+------------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+
| Message                                  | Adress         | Test             |
|------------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+
| Hello World                              | up             |               up |
| Hello Everyone Here                      | up             |             down |
| Hi there. My name is Eric. How are you?  | up             |         inactive |
+------------------------------------------+----------------+------------------+
+----------------------------+----------------+------------------+
| Message                    | Adress         | Test             |
|----------------------------+----------------+------------------+
| What's up?                 | up             |               up |
| Hi. I'm Otilia             | up             |             down |
| Hi there. This is Marcus   | up             |         inactive |
+----------------------------+----------------+------------------+
```

For `fldlist="4,3,2"` this generates:

```
+----------------+---------------+------------------------------------------+
| Adress         | Status        | Message                                  |
+----------------+---------------|------------------------------------------+
| up             | Active        | Hello World                              |
| up             | Passive       | Hello Everyone Here                      |
| up             | Down          | Hi there. My name is Eric. How are you?  |
+----------------+---------------+------------------------------------------+
+----------------+---------------+----------------------------+
| Adress         | Status        | Message                    |
+----------------+---------------|----------------------------+
| up             | Active        | What's up?                 |
| up             | Passive       | Hi. I'm Otilia             |
| up             | Up            | Hi there. This is Marcus   |
+----------------+---------------+----------------------------+
```

Say that again? (`fldlist="3,3,3"`):

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Status        | Status        | Status        |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Active        | Active        | Active        |
| Passive       | Passive       | Passive       |
| Down          | Down          | Down          |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Status        | Status        | Status        |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Active        | Active        | Active        |
| Passive       | Passive       | Passive       |
| Up            | Up            | Up            |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

And if you make the mistake of trying to print the '1st' column, ie, `fldlist="1"`:

```
+
|
|
|
|
|
+
+
|
|
|
|
|
+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @markp-fuso , this works like a charm! My understanding is that you used arrays. Suppose I want to introduce variables inside AWK to replace the given numbers. How would I do that? If I simple replace them in; such as: awk -v fldlist='$First_col,$Second_col' it won't work - sorry I'm new to AWK.

Comment: @crilex to have `bash` variables substituted into the `awk` variable `fldlist` just wrap the `bash` variable reference(s) in double quotes; I've updated the answer to replace the single quotes with double quotes where appropriate; for hardcoded values the single and double quotes work the same (ie, `fldlist="1,2,3"` is the same as `fldlist='1,2,3'`), but for using `bash` variables we need to use double quotes (eg, `fldlist="$First_col,$Second_col"`); also ... the contents of the `awk` variable `fldlist` are still being parsed and stored in the `awk` array `fields[]`

Comment: got it, thanks again @markp-fuso !

Answer (score 1):

If `GNU awk` is available, please try markp-fuso's nice solution.
If not, here is a posix-compliant alternative:

```
#!/bin/bash

# define bash variables
cols=(2 3 6)                            # bash array of desired columns
col_list=$(IFS=,; echo "${cols[*]}")    # create a csv string

awk -v cols="$col_list" '
NR==FNR {
    if (match($0, /^[|+]/)) {           # the record contains a table
        if (match($0, /^[|+]-/))        # horizontally ruled line
            n = split($0, a, /[|+]/)    # split into columns
        else                            # "cell" line
            n = split($0, a, /\|/)
        len = 0
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            len += length(a[i]) + 1     # accumulated column position
            pos[FNR, i] = len
        }
    }
    next
}
{
    n = split(cols, a, /,/)             # split the variable `cols` on comma into an array
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        col = a[i]
        if (pos[FNR, col] && pos[FNR, col+1]) {
            printf("%s", substr($0, pos[FNR, col], pos[FNR, col + 1] - pos[FNR, col]))
        }
    }
    print(substr($0, pos[FNR, col + 1], 1))
}
' file.txt file.txt
```

Result with `cols=(2 3 6)` as shown above:

```
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+
| Status        | Adress         | Calibration     |
+---------------+----------------+-----------------|
| Active        | up             |            done |
| Passive       | up             |            none |
| Down          | up             |            done |
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+
| Status        | Adress         | Calibration     |
+---------------+----------------+-----------------|
| Active        | up             |            done |
| Passive       | up             |            none |
| Up            | up             |            done |
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

It detects the column width in the 1st pass then splits the line on the column position in the 2nd pass.
You can control the columns to print with the bash array `cols` which is assigned at the beginning of the script. Please assign the array to the list of desired column numbers in increasing order. If you want to use the bash variable in different way, please let me know.

Comment: Interesting approach, yes I would want to be able to print multiple columns at the time and also to use external variables within the AWK. Thanks a lot @tshiono !

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated my script accordingly. If you want to change the way of assigning bash variable(s), please let me know. BR.